# I can't run Debug mode on the Cloud Code plugin in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, skaffold, google-cloud-code

I want to debug my simple flask app (hello-world Skaffold sample) on the local Kubernetes cluster but when I click debug button, Skaffold runs in dev mode and doesn't open debug page.

Does anybody know what should I do to fix this problem?

my Scaffold config file is:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta2
kind: Config
metadata:
  annotations:
    debug.cloud.google.com/config: "{}"
  name: python-skaffold
build:
  local:
    push: true
    useDockerCLI: true
  artifacts:
  - image: 192.168.22.17:5001/python-hello-world
    context: src

manifests:
  rawYaml:
  - kubernetes-manifests/hello.deployment.yaml
  - kubernetes-manifests/hello.service.yaml
```

I tried all platforms (Minikube and Extera k8s cluster) but don't work.

Comment: Cloud Code only supports Python debugging with PyCharm Professional or IntelliJ Ultimate with Python plugin installed. Are you running one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The problem was that the image name I used in the scaffold file differed from the image name in the deployment file, so it didn't work.

When running debug, it checks the image names in the files; if it's different, it doesn't work.